# ¿Se puede mandar llamar dos modelos a una vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

tengo un sistema en el cual quiero dar de alta a un "Agente"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es llenar en la parte de `SucursalEmpresa` con la información que esta en su propia tabla en un SelectList, pero no puedo mandar llamar dos modelos en una sola vista.

Este es mi modelo de Agente:

```
public class AgenteM
{
    public string Agente { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo Nombre es obligatorio")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Familia { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Estatus { get; set; }
    public int SucursalEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Y este es mi modelo de Sucursal:

```
public class SucursalM
{
    public int Sucursal { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Guardar(AgenteM oAgente)
    {
        //Recibe el objeto para guardarlo en BD

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        var respuesta = _AgenteD.Guardar(oAgente);

        if (respuesta == true)
            return RedirectToAction("Listar");
        else
        return View();
    }
```

donde mando a llamar mi función `Guardar`

```
    public bool Guardar(AgenteM oAgente)
    {
        ListarSucursal();
        bool rpta;
        try
        {
            var cn = new Conexion();

            using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(cn.GetCadenaSql()))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_WebCrearAgente", conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Agente", oAgente.Agente);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombre", oAgente.Nombre);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SucursalEmpresa", oAgente.SucursalEmpresa);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tipo", oAgente.Tipo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Estatus", oAgente.Estatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Familia", oAgente.Familia);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            rpta = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
            rpta = false;
        }

        return rpta;
    }
```

aquí tengo una función para traer toda la información de las sucursales:

```
    public List<SucursalM> ListarSucursal()
    {
        var oLista = new List<SucursalM>();
        var cn = new Conexion();

        using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(cn.GetCadenaSql()))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_WebObtenerSucursales", conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    oLista.Add(new SucursalM()
                    {
                        Sucursal = (int)dr["Sucursal"],
                        Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return oLista;
    }
```

Y esta es mi vista, donde quiero llenar un selectList con la información de la tabla.

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-label">Agente</label>
                <input asp-for="Agente" type="text" class="form-control" name="Agente">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                <input asp-for="Nombre" type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombre">
                <span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-label">Sucursal Empresa</label>
                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgenteM.SucursalM.Sucursal, new SelectList(Model.AgenteM.SucursalM.Sucursales, "Sucursal", "Nombre"), "Selecciona una Sucursal", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtSucursal", @placeholder = "Sucursal" })*@
                <input asp-for="SucursalEmpresa" type="text" class="form-control" name="SucursalEmpresa">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="form-label">Tipo</label>
                <input asp-for="Tipo" type="text" class="form-control" name="Tipo">
            </div>

        </div>
```

¿Qué me esta fallando o que estoy haciendo mal? Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Sí, sí se puede, se utiliza un ViewModel. Te recomiendo este workshop: https://youtu.be/6LZG76aLykY Tiene un buen fundamento del framework de Aspnet MVC. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede pasar 2 modelos a la vista.

Lo que se puede hacer es:

1. Para casos donde la vista se compone de 2 o más modelos es crear una clase que contenga todos los modelos.
2. Para casos como el tuyo, donde es solo llenar un select lo que normalmente se utiliza es un ViewBag o un ViewData

En el action que genera tu vista colocas

```
ViewBag.sucursales = new SelectList(ListarSucursal(), "Sucursal", "Nombre");
```

El primer argumento es la lista, el segundo es el nombre de la propiedad que hace de ID, y el tercer es el nombre de la propiedad que hace de Text

Existe un 4to parámetro para indicar el seleccionado, que se usa cuando editas un elemento que ya existe, es decir en la vista de Editar

```
ViewBag.sucursales = new SelectList(ListarSucursal(), "Sucursal", "Nombre", Item.Sucursal);
```

Luego en tu vista colocas:

```
<select asp-for="SucursalEmpresa" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.sucursales"></select>
```

O si quieres crearlo a pulso:

En el controlador

```
ViewBag.sucursales = ListarSucursal();
```

En la vista

```
<select asp-for="SucursalEmpresa" class="form-control">
    @foreach(var sucursal in ViewBag.sucursales as List<SucursalM>)
    {
      <option label="@sucursal.Sucursal" value="@sucursal.Nombre"></option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, me funciono muy bien!

Comment: @Hectorepg si consideras esta es la respuesta correcta, ayuda a las demás marcándola como la respuesta corecta.